# SQL Server connection string for service account

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# solution which will connect to TFS (Team Foundation Server) to download files and then deploy them to the SQL Server ETL machine by connecting it to the ETL server. Since I am executing it on my local machine, I am using a Windows authentication SQL Server connection string which includes `Integrated Security=SSPI`.

But now, we want to use the same solution by using SQL Server authentication from the service account where we will be given the loginID and password. So, what should be changes in my code for connection string if it is a service account with login and password details?

I already have a C# solution where I am currently trying to modify the code.

```
// Creating a connection
string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=" + SSISServerName +
";Initial Catalog=SSISDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=*****;Password=*****";
// "Data Source=ETLET0083;Initial Catalog=SSISDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

// Creating a SSIS object
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.IntegrationServices integrationServices = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.IntegrationServices(sqlConnection);
Catalog catalog;
```

Comment: Firstly, do *NOT* post the string showing your username/password combination to the whole internet.

Comment: You'll also want to change `Integrated Security=SSPI` to `Persist Security Info=True;` .

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are writing this type of code, you should avoid using SQL authentication and hard-coding the username and password at all.

For a service account, create a Windows account, give it permissions in the DB, and change back to using integrated security.